# Android : Fragment is reloaded after onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I made a post early on a existing solved thread, and a moderator advices me to create a new post.

n a two pane app, I have a MainActivity controls some datas on device, ask for login if needed, then start a master flow detail activity (TopicListActivity).

The master flow have a classic look and feel, and I replace content container with a FragmentManager.replace(). It can be a sublist, or an item in sublist. very basic.

On the item fragment, i have a button to start an intent : RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH

I start it basically : startActivityForResult(intentWithMyExtraParams, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);

And this fragment (item page) handles onActivityResult callback. After triggered it, get the recognized text to set it in a TextView then finish properly this callback, the item fragment is reloaded, and the Bundle provided by onCreateView is null.

I tried a new master flow project to check if the problem happens. Not happened. After onActivityResult, fragment is not reloaded and my TextView.setText() is not lost by fragment reloading.

I tried to put a ItemPageFragment as a variable in ItemTopicListActivity, handle it when a new item asked, add button click (to start recognizer) in ItemFragment callback in order his parent, ItemTopicListActivity, handles this activity, then send information by using fragment method on the handleded variable, but I had the same result, fragment is reloaded.

I tried to put some extra config in the manifest, likes : android:alwaysRetainTaskState on ItemTopicListActivity allowsBackup=true on app element noHistory=false

I have no more idea ...

Thanks to all

Comment: have you written any code in your onResume() method ? because after onActivityresult() is being called the onResume() will be called. so make sure.

Comment: or have you added android:launchMode="singleTask" in your app manifest file ?

Comment: OK, i found. 

From my ItemTopicListActivity, I extends onResume() method which reloaded my fragment ... 

My mistake 

I had started to write my answer but I forgot to post ! 

Thanks